# Selecting a value from a dropdown list in coded-ui test is now "contains" instead of "exact" in vs2012

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

To be more specific...

I use this to select a value from a dropdown list during a coded ui test... this extracts value from a specific row in a csv and selects it in the DDL.

```
        this.UIMap.MarketCodeType2Params.UIMarketsComboBoxSelectedItem = TestContext.DataRow["IFAGeneralMarketCodeType"].ToString();
```

The value is

> ABC123

When the test runs... the first value it finds in the Application DDL which is the default value is

> ABC123 222

And it selects it.. in VS2010, it looked for the exact value it is being compared with. Now in 2012, it's trying to be smart and is selecting the first one that contains the value is has...

Any help would be appreciated..
I tried adding if's and do while's, but they all assert on the value coming from CSV and not value selected. When i managed to assert on the value selected, the test run kept looping, selecting the wrong one then opening DDL again(when it realizes its supposed not to) and selects it again..

The selection function in VS2012 is messed...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it was solved, a very terrible way, but i can't do any better being on limited time.

```
        uICcmbMarketsComboBox.SelectedItem = this.ClientCreationRecParams.UICcmbMarketsComboBoxSelectedItem;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < uIMarketsComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            if (uIMarketsComboBox.Items[i].Name.ToString() != "ABC123")
            {
                continue;
            }
            else x = i;

        }
        uIMarketsComboBox.SelectedIndex = x
```

Why'd they have to break ComboBox Selection in VS2012?!.... :(

Comment: I am trying to do this in VS 2017 on a WPF combo box. Your solution looks good but doesn't work for me.